# How to stop my bubbles animation from flickering? Tried nearly everything

Tags: java, swing, animation, flicker

I'm in despair, because my animation isn't as smooth as I expected. So I know, there is a lot of stuff around this problem, but mine is different in that way, that I know the common problems and I think, I'm doing it right. So firstly, this is my code:

**Game.java**

```
import de.lwerner.collisions.CircleCollision;
import de.lwerner.collisions.math.Vector2D;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 25);
    private static final Color TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int TARGET_FPS = 60;

    private javax.swing.Timer swingTimer;

    private JFrame window;

    private Timer timer;
    private Timer fpsTimer;

    private int counter;
    private long[] diffs;
    private int fps;

    private LinkedList<Circle> circles;
    private LinkedList<Sprite> sprites;

    public Game() {
        timer = new Timer();
        fpsTimer = new Timer(System.currentTimeMillis());

        diffs = new long[TARGET_FPS];

        circles = new LinkedList<>();
        circles.add(new Circle(100, 100, 50, 300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(250, 250, 50, 300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(400, 400, 50, 300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(550, 550, 50, 300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(700, 700, 50, 300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(100, 700, 50, -300, 300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(250, 550, 50, 300, -300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(550, 250, 50, 300, -300, Color.WHITE));
//        circles.add(new Circle(700, 100, 50, -300, 300, Color.WHITE));

        sprites = new LinkedList<>();
        sprites.addAll(circles);

        window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setContentPane(this);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.validate();
        window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });
        window.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(window);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (Sprite s: sprites) {
            s.render(g);
        }

        g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        g.drawString(fps + " FPS", 10, 20);

        diffs[counter % TARGET_FPS] = fpsTimer.tick();
        if (++counter % TARGET_FPS == 0) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (long diff: diffs) {
                sum += diff;
            }
            fps = 1000 / (sum / TARGET_FPS);
        }
    }

    private void step() {
        long tick = timer.tick();
        for (Sprite s: sprites) {
            s.update(tick);
        }
        repaint();
        checkCollisions();
    }

    private void checkCollisions() {
        for (Sprite s1: sprites) {
            BoundingBox bb = s1.getBoundingBox();
            int offset = 0;
            if (s1 instanceof Circle) {
                offset = ((Circle) s1).getRadius();
            }
            if (bb.getLeft() < 0 || bb.getRight() >= getWidth()) {
                s1.setVelX(-s1.getVelX());

                if (bb.getLeft() < 0) {
                    s1.setX(0 + offset);
                } else {
                    s1.setX(getWidth() - 1 - offset);
                }
            }
            if (bb.getTop() < 0 || bb.getBottom() >= getHeight()) {
                s1.setVelY(-s1.getVelY());

                if (bb.getTop() < 0) {
                    s1.setY(0 + offset);
                } else {
                    s1.setY(getHeight() - 1 - offset);
                }
            }
        }

//        Set<Set<Circle>> collidingPairs = new HashSet<>();
//        for (Circle c1: circles) {
//            for (Circle c2: circles) {
//                if (c1 == c2) {
//                    continue;
//                } else {
//                    if (c1.intersects(c2)) {
//                        Set<Circle> pair = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(c1, c2));
//                        if (!collidingPairs.contains(pair)) {
//                            collidingPairs.add(pair);
//                            de.lwerner.collisions.Circle cc1 = new de.lwerner.collisions.Circle(c1.getX(), c1.getY(), c1.getRadius(), new Vector2D(c1.getVelX(), c1.getVelY()));
//                            de.lwerner.collisions.Circle cc2 = new de.lwerner.collisions.Circle(c2.getX(), c2.getY(), c2.getRadius(), new Vector2D(c2.getVelX(), c2.getVelY()));
//                            CircleCollision collision = new CircleCollision(cc1, cc2);
//                            collision.resolveCollision();
//                            Vector2D v1New = cc1.getV();
//                            Vector2D v2New = cc2.getV();
//                            c1.setVelX((int) v1New.getX());
//                            c1.setVelY((int) v1New.getY());
//                            c2.setVelX((int) v2New.getX());
//                            c2.setVelY((int) v2New.getY());
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (swingTimer.isRunning()) {
            swingTimer.stop();
            window.dispose();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        swingTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000 / TARGET_FPS, this);
        swingTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        step();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Game().start());
    }
}
```

**Sprite.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Sprite {

    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected int velX;
    protected int velY;

    public Sprite(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this(x, y, width, height, 0, 0);
    }

    public Sprite(int x, int y, int width, int height, int velX, int velY) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (int)Math.round(x);
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (int)Math.round(y);
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getVelX() {
        return velX;
    }

    public void setVelX(int velX) {
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public int getVelY() {
        return velY;
    }

    public void setVelY(int velY) {
        this.velY = velY;
    }

    public void update(long tick) {
        x += tick * velX / 1000.0;
        y += tick * velY / 1000.0;
    }

    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        return new BoundingBox(getY(), getX() + width, getY() + height, getX());
    }

    public boolean intersects(Sprite other) {
        return getBoundingBox().intersects(other.getBoundingBox());
    }

    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

}
```

**Circle.java**

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Circle extends Sprite {

    private Color color;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        super(x, y, r * 2, r * 2);
        color = c;
//        try {
//            loadImage();
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//
//        }
    }

    public Circle(int x, int y, int r, int velX, int velY, Color c) {
        super(x, y, r * 2, r * 2, velX, velY);
        color = c;
//        try {
//            loadImage();
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//
//        }
    }

    private void loadImage() throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/bubble.png"));
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return width / 2;
    }

    public boolean intersects(Circle other) {
        int dx = Math.abs(getX() - other.getX());
        int dy = Math.abs(getY() - other.getY());
        int r1 = getRadius();
        int r2 = other.getRadius();
        return dx * dx + dy * dy < (r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2);
    }

    @Override
    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        return new BoundingBox(getY() - getRadius(), getX() + getRadius(), getY() + getRadius(), getX() - getRadius());
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(getX() - getRadius(), getY() - getRadius(), width, height);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, getX() - getRadius(), getY() - getRadius(), null);
        }
    }

}
```

**Timer.java**

```
public class Timer {

    private long lastTime;

    public Timer() {
        this(0L);
    }

    public Timer(long initialTime) {
        lastTime = initialTime;
    }

    public long tick() {
        if (lastTime == 0) {
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return 0;
        }
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = current - lastTime;
        lastTime = current;
        return diff;
    }

}
```

**BoundingBox.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

public class BoundingBox {

    private int top;
    private int right;
    private int bottom;
    private int left;

    public BoundingBox(int top, int right, int bottom, int left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.left = left;
    }

    public int getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public int getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public int getBottom() {
        return bottom;
    }

    public int getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle() {
        return new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
    }

    public boolean intersects(BoundingBox other) {
        return getRectangle().intersects(other.getRectangle());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BoundingBox{" +
                "top=" + top +
                ", right=" + right +
                ", bottom=" + bottom +
                ", left=" + left +
                '}';
    }

}
```

So I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. Common problems such as calling paint(), using not-doublebuffered components, using wrong methods for periodically run code and so on aren't present, yet it's flickering. The FPS are constant.

So, please help me! I'd be very glad to come over this...

Thanks!

Comment: On what platform and with which Java version are you running?  I don't see any flickering in Java 8 on 64-bit Windows 7 or 64-bit Debian Linux.

Comment: I've tested it on Windows 7, Windows 10, Linux Mint and Ubuntu with Java 8 on relatively fast machines, on any computer it's flickering. As I said, I don't think, it's a performance problem, but a Java problem. That's just weird...
@trashgod How is this helpful for my problem?